# TypeError: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x3ee9890; DATETIME> is not serializable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the sqlalchemy for writing one of the GET API. Underlaying database is postgresSQL.
My datetime column is not getting json serialized. Can you please help me to resolve this issue:

**Model Class:** 
**models\rpt.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class RptModel(db.Model):

      __tablename__='rpt_detail'

      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      user_nm = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100), nullable=False)
      created_dt = db.column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))

      def __init__(self, _id, user_nm, created_dt):
           self.id = _id
           self.user_nm = user_nm
           self.created_dt = created_dt

      def json():
           return {'id': self.id, 'user_nm': self.user_nm, 'created_dt': self.created_dt}

      @classmethod
      def get_rpt_by_id(Cls, id):
          return Cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

**Resource Class**
**resources\rpt.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from models.rpt import RptModel

class GetRpt(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        rpt = RptModel.get_rpt_by_id(id)
        if rpt:
           return rpt.json(), 200
        return {'message': 'rpt not found'}, 404
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.rpt import GetRpt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['POSTGRESQL_USER'] = 'AAAA'
app.config['POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD'] = 'BBBB'
app.config['POSTGRESQL_HOST'] = 'CCCC.DDD.COM'
app.config['POSTGRESQL_DB'] = 'EEEE'

postgres_db_uri = 'postgresql://'+app.config['POSTGRESQL_USER']+':'+app.config['POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD']+'@'+app.config['POSTGRESQL_HOST']+'/'+app.config['POSTGRESQL_DB']

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgres_db_uri
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

api = APi(app)
api.add_resource(GetRpt, 'rpt/<string:id>')

if __name__='__main__':
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Postgres RPT Table**
Table: rpt_detail

```
column     Type                     Collation Nullable Default
id         integer                            not null nextval('rpt_detail_id_seq'::regclass)
user_nm    character varying(100)             not null
created_dt timestamp with time zone           not null
```

When I'm trying to hit this from the postman, I'm getting error stating

```
TypeError: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x3ee9890; DATETIME> is not JSON serializable
```

I'm not able to convert the created_dt field to JSON format. Can anyone provide any resolution to this.

Comment: I think there’s a missing quotation mark in your code. Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Please include the full traceback (with proper formatting), and a working example. Your `json()` method definition for example lacks the `self` argument it requires.